# Bootstrap DateTimePicker - choose Month (YYYY-MM format)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/e31m02L9/2/

How can I have DateTimePicker pick a month instead of a date and time? (So the value is `YYYY-MM`)

Looking at online documentation I was told to use `startView`:

```
$('#datetimepickerday').datetimepicker({
    startView: "month"
});
```

But it gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: updated your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use [`viewMode`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewmode) instead of `startView` and set [`format`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option  to `YYYY-MM`. If you specify `format: 'YYYY-MM'` with eonasdan datetimepicker the default behaviour is to show the months dropdown (no need to explicitly set `viewMode`)

Here a working example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM',
  viewMode: 'months'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```